# Inserting a value in a SQL query meant for joining two tables

Tags: c#, sql, get

```
[Route("v1/orderhistory/{orderId}")]
[HttpGet()]
public List<OrderHistoryItemDto> GetOrderItem(int orderId)
{
    using (var con = _connFactory())
    {
        con.Open();
        return con.Query<OrderHistoryItemDto>(@"select * from orderhistory inner join orderhistoryitem 
        on orderhistory.@orderId = orderhistoryitem.@orderId", new { orderId }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run this code, I am getting the following error:

> 'Incorrect syntax near '@orderId'.'

Basically what I am trying to do is get a full list of values contained in these two tables (OrderHistory and OrderHistoryItem). The thing I am doing wrong here is writing the SQL query, but I can not find any way to properly insert it in the ON clause without getting a syntax error.

Comment: do normal join(by right columns) and then use parameter `@orderId` in  where clause

Comment: Suggest using something like `Entity Framework` for querying database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how SQL works. You specify the columns to join on, in this case the names of the 2 id columns that should match and then use a WHERE clause to define which column needs to match the passed in `@orderId`. So your query will look something like this:

```
select * 
from orderhistory 
inner join orderhistoryitem on orderhistory.orderItemId = orderhistoryitem.orderId
where orderhistory.orderItemId = @orderId
```

The assumption here is that `orderhistory` has a column that holds the `orderId` called something like `orderItemId`, which should match the `orderId` column (or whatever it's called) in the `orderhistoryitem` table. You then pass in an order Id as a parameter and filter based on that in the 'where' clause.

How you execute that is up to you. There are many options such as Entity Framework, Dapper, calling a function / stored procedure, straight up in line SQL etc. However, you will need to create a `SqlParameter` to fill with you actual order Id value and pass that to the SQL.